# Is Ubuntu Software exactly the same as Snap Store in 20.04?

Tags: software-center, snap, 20.04

I had some hiccups in upgrading 19.10 to 20.04. After the upgrade, I couldn't open Ubuntu Software, and Gnome Software has been removed.

### Background

Looking for the exact command Ubuntu Software was opened, I found this using menulibre:

```
env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/snap-store_ubuntu-software.desktop /snap/bin/snap-store.ubuntu-software %U
```

This however, could not be opened due to some permission error. It first couldn't allow run `sed ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`. Then it couldn't `mkdir /run/user/0`. I figured I should reinstall Snap Store again, seeing that the above command is related to Snap Store.

Then with some more permission error fixing endeavor, I removed the installed Ubuntu Store Snap Store, and `snap install snap-store`. The icon is now a hummingbird (I assume) instead of the orange bag with an "A".

---

So are they the exact same piece of software, but one is skinned? If not, how can I reinstall `snap-store.ubuntu-software` back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one in Ubuntu is on a separate channel. Run:

```bsh
snap refresh snap-store --channel=stable/ubuntu-20.04
```

This above is based on the output of `snap info snap-store`, part of which is shown below:

```
commands:
  - snap-store
  - snap-store.ubuntu-software
  - snap-store.ubuntu-software-local-file
snap-id:      gjf3IPXoRiipCu9K0kVu52f0H56fIksg
tracking:     latest/stable/ubuntu-20.04
refresh-date: 4 days ago, at 16:24 IST
channels:
  latest/stable:    3.31.1+git187.84b64e0b 2020-04-22 (415) 45MB -
  latest/candidate: 3.31.1+git187.84b64e0b 2020-04-20 (415) 45MB -
  latest/beta:      3.36.0-75-g02a9109     2020-04-23 (436) 52MB -
  latest/edge:      20200414.ac9047f       2020-04-14 (375) 50MB -
installed:          3.36.0-74-ga164ec9                (433) 52MB -
```

Comment: Can you please explain how you get `--channel=stable/ubuntu-20.04`? That's not listed in `snap info snap-store`.

Comment: Just run `snap info snap-store` on normal 20.04 install.  See "tracking"

Comment: That's what I did.

Comment: Well I mean before you remove and reinstall it.  I get it from my machine.

Comment: I ran `snap info snap-store` on a clean Ubuntu 20.04 in which I didn't have to uninstall/reinstall anything. The last line of that output is `installed:          3.36.0-74-ga164ec9                (433) 52MB -`. And that's after running `snap refresh`.

Comment: There's a line: `tracking:     latest/stable/ubuntu-20.04`, tracking indicates which channel you're on.

Comment: If you don't mind, I'll edit your answer to include partial output. You can remove it if you feel it isn't required.